# Получение массива из php и перевод его в формат json

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Получил обычный массив из формы на php.

```
Array ( [0] => name0 [1] => name1 [2] => name2 [3] => name3 [4] => name4 [5] => name5 [6] => name6)
```

Требуется перевести его в ассоциативный массив и за тем представить массив в формате json. Пример файла Json, который нужно получить:

```
{
"PC": [
{"name": "name0"},
{"name": "name1"}, 
]
```

Comment: вы уверены что с массивом ничего не перепутали? это какая форма такой массив возвращает?

Comment: `json_encode($array)` делает из массива $array json-строку

Comment: Получаю из формы массив имен <input type="text" name="name_node[]">

Comment: а в чем смысл ключ дублировать? чем просто массив имён не устраивает? 
можете написать что делаете?

Comment: Ввожу в форму количество требуемых точек графа, генерируются имена точек, передаю и получаю соответственно массив имен, далее требуется перевод в json формат, где первый ключ PC указывает на массив с именами, а второй ключ на имена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаете преобразование в нужный формат с помощью цикла и функции `json_encode()`, затем выводите на экран, либо же записываете в файл.

```
$array = ['name0', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $new['PC'][]['name'] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($new); // {"PC":[{"name":"name0"},{"name":"name1"} ... {"name":"name4"}]}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Работает как надо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php):

```
$array = Array(0 => 'name0', 1 => 'name1');
$result = json_encode(array('PC' => $array));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Прочтите внимательнее какой формат требуется на выходе у автора вопроса. И сравните со своим.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie согласен, поспешил 

Comment: посмотри здесь еще пример, тот же цикл, только с `array_map()` - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25f67c52d852ffd5c684cf20aa8e72dd1045ec5b